# Error when creating repository using GitHub Desktop app

Tags: github

I messed up the previous repository and then I deleted it from GitHub. When I try to create one locally using GitHub Desktop app, I am getting an error saying some files are too large:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self explanatory. You are attempting to add some files to the repository which are over 100 MB, which GitHub doesn't allow.

You can add whatever file size in a local Git repository, but you won't be able to push the changes to GitHub.

- [Working with large files](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files)